# Creating the instance of Kotlin Coroutine's flow similar to channel or broadcast channel

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Similar to channels and broadcast channels, can flows also be instantiated and reused at multiple places?

General usage of creating flows is wrapping the logic to emit the data inside the flow's body and is returned.

Snippet :

```
fun listenToDataChanges() : Flow<T>
{
return flow {
            dataSource.querySomeInfo()?.consumeEach { 
                data->
                if (someCondition) {
                    emit(data)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Everytime listenToDataChanges() is called, a new flow instance is created and multiple subscriptions would be made. Instead is it possible to create and reuse the instance to avoid multiple subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to store it in a variable instead of recreating the flow each time
By the way it seems like you could simplify this way:

```
val customFlow = dataSource.querySomeInfo()?.filter { someCondition }
```